# How to add a class constraint to a Functor instance declaration in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functor

I have defined the following data type:

```
data Probability a = PD { mass :: [(a, Ratio Int)] }
```

Now I want to write that it is an instance of `Functor`:

```
collect :: (Eq a, Num b) => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
collect al = map collect' keys where
    keys = nub $ map fst al
    collect' k = (k, sum (map snd (matches k)))
    matches k = filter ((==) k . fst) al

instance (Eq a) => Functor (Probability a) where
    fmap f p = PD (collect $ map (first f) (mass p))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Kind mis-match
The first argument of `Functor' should have kind `* -> *',
but `Probability a' has kind `*'
In the instance declaration for `Functor (Probability a)'
```

How can I add the necessary `Eq a` constraint?  (I'm using GHC 7.4.1)

Comment: You can't add the `Eq` constraint, because that violates what it *means* to be an instance of `Functor`.

Comment: there is a real good talk about this problem here: http://vimeo.com/69261960 (some of the answers solutions are explained there too)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly, you can't do that—`Functor` instances must accept any kind of mapping function without restriction.

You can kind of fake it, though.

```
newtype PF a = PF { unPF :: forall r . Eq r => (a -> r) -> Probability r }

instance Functor PF where
  fmap f (PF p) = PF (\mp -> p (mp . f))
```

Here, all of the functions that would be mapped over `Probability` have been "deferred" by `PF`. We run them all at once by "lowering" back into `Probability` when possible

```
lowerPF :: Eq a => PF a -> Probability a
lowerPF pf = unPF pf id
```

And in order to convert a `Probability` into a `fmappable` `PF` we must "lift" it

```
liftPF :: Probability a -> PF a
liftPF p = PF $ \mp -> PD (collect $ map (first mp) (mass p))
```

Comment: what is `f` in `liftPF`?

Comment: Oops, teach me to copy and paste—it was supposed to be `mp`. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 5):

What you're writing is not a `Functor`. A `Functor`'s `fmap` must support *arbitrary* value types being mapped, not just those that satisfy a certain constraint.  You can make it an instance of a more general concept though.  For example, the package [constrained-categories](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/constrained-categories) defines a class of constrained functors.