# Arbitrary class constraints when implementing type classes in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement a simple `Set` in Haskell, and am getting stuck with how to express class constraints for the elements it contains.

The `Set` type class is fairly simple:

```
class Set s where
  empty    :: s a
  isEmpty  :: s a -> Bool
  insert   :: s a -> a -> s a
  contains :: s a -> a -> Bool
```

A trivial implementation of a `Set` is a binary search tree:

```
data BinarySearchTree a = Node a (BinarySearchTree a) (BinarySearchTree a) | Leaf
```

I'm getting somewhat stuck when it comes to declaring the correct class constraints, however:

- `Set` requires, at the very least, the ability to decide whether two elements are equal - its values need to have an instance of `Eq`.
- `BinarySearchTree` requires its elements to have an instance of `Ord`, since each node needs to have the smaller element on the left and the bigger on the right.

The first, simple solution is to update `Set`'s signature to require `a` to have an instance of `Eq`:

```
class Set s where
  empty    :: Eq a => s a
  isEmpty  :: Eq a => s a -> Bool
  insert   :: Eq a => s a -> a -> s a
  contains :: Eq a => s a -> a -> Bool
```

Implementing an instance of `Set` for `BinarySearchTree` is not a problem: `Ord` implies `Eq`, so I can "override' the class constraints.

What if, however, `BinarySearchTree` required some exotic class contraints, ones that are entirely incompatible with `Eq`? How do I express these and keep the type checker happy?

The only way I can think of is to add a class constraint on `BinarySearchTree`, something like:

```
data Ord a => BinarySearchTree a = Node a (BinarySearchTree a) (BinarySearchTree a) | Leaf
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to satisfy the type checker: even though the declaration guarantees that `BinarySearchTree` *must* contain elements with an `Ord` instance, this constraint doesn't seem to carry over to functions that use `BinarySearchTree` - it's as if the class constraint only applied to the data constructors, but were then forgotten about.

What am I missing? Is there an elegant solution for what I'm trying to do, or even a solution at all?

Comment: It seems that one of my points is incorrect: I was *certain* I had managed to do the whole "`Eq` on `Set`, `Ord` on `BinarySearchTree`" thing but I can't get that to compile anymore....

Comment: Note: this question is related to another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345055/how-to-add-a-class-constraint-to-a-functor-instance-declaration-in-haskell. Not sure if it's close enough to be considered a duplicate...

Comment: I'm not sure they qualify as duplicates, even though they do both seem to come from the same root problem. Either way is fine by me, and I would not be offended for my question to be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're asking about a well-known problem in Haskell: how to define a type class such that instances of the type class can define the type class constraints they require for the type class's operations.  This problem often appears on discussion forums in the form of the question "Why is `Data.Set` not an instance of `Functor`?" and then the problem is that `Data.Set` has a map function with an additional `Ord` constraint:

```
Data.Set.map :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
```

while Functor's fmap method looks like

```
class Functor f where
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Since a few years, solutions to the problem exist.  One solution combines the relatively new extension ConstraintKinds with TypeFamilies. For your example, it would amount to something like this:

```
class Set s where
  type SetCt s a :: Constraint
  empty    :: s a
  isEmpty  :: s a -> Bool
  insert   :: Ct a => s a -> a -> s a
  contains :: Ct a => s a -> a -> Bool
```

The instance for BinarySearchTree would then look like

```
instance Set BinarySearchTree where
  type SetCt BinarySearchTree a = Ord a
  ...
```

Here is a [blog post](http://dorchard.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/constraint-kinds-in-haskell-finally-bringing-us-constraint-families/) by Dominic Orchard which explains these ideas in a bit more detail.

Comment: In my very specific case, it seems I can solve the problem with `ExistentialQuantification` by not setting any constraint on `Set` and adding the `Ord a` constraint to `BinarySearchTree`'s data constructors. Is there any particular reason not to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Do you keep the Set class as shown in your original question?  If so, what prevents me from calling `insert (insert empty x) y` for `x` and `y` of a type `a` without an `Ord a` instance?

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't very clear. I've answered my own question to provide more details and would appreciate any insight you might have - I'm enough of a Haskell beginner that odds are good I'm not seeing all the consequences of the implementation I propose.

Answer (score 0):

I've got something that seems to work.

It requires redefining `Set` as follows:

```
class Set s where
  isEmpty  :: s a -> Bool
  insert   :: s a -> a -> s a
  contains :: s a -> a -> Bool
```

Note the differences with the earlier definition:

- there is no class constraint.
- there is no `empty` method.

Having defined `Set` that way, I can then define `BinarySearchTree` as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
data BinarySearchTree a = Ord a => Node a (BinarySearchTree a) (BinarySearchTree a)
                        | Ord a => Leaf
```

This works, because `BinarySearchTree` cannot be constructed without an implicit `Ord` anymore - whenever you get an instance `BinarySearchTree a`, you also have `Ord a`.

Note that this required changing the `Set` signature not to include an `empty` definition anymore: since it does not receive an instance of `BinarySearchTree a` but must create one, there is no way to enforce the `Ord a` constraint.

In this specific instance, I don't believe this to be much of an issue: unless I'm mistaken, in order to use the `empty` method, you'd need to explicitly type its return value. As long as you're going to do that, you might as well use the empty constructor for the underlying implementation.

Comment: Sure, if you don't need an overloaded `empty`, then this works.  It does mean that any function that does need `empty` will necessarily be restricted to a single `Set` implementation. Depending on your use case, this may not be a problem, but it does limit the generality of your solution.