# Constructor Class/Functor for a constrained element type?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor

This is a FAQ -- [for example this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25422824/2840542); or Section 3.2 'A Constraint for Well-Formed Applications' in 'Partial Type Constructors' [Jones, Morris, Eisenberg 2020]. And the frequent answer is you can't do it. I think I kinda have done it. (But it ain't pretty.)

```
data Set a = NilSet | ConsSet a (Set a)    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)
mySet = ConsSet 'a' $ ConsSet 'b' $ ConsSet 'A' NilSet
```

My `Set` type should not have duplicate elements. So if I `fmap toUpper mySet`, I want to avoid two `'A'`s. Then consider

**Addit:** in response to comments. (Original code retained below, for reference.)

> @Carl [the restriction in the Language Report] applies only to constraints on exactly the type `u`.

Yes I didn't even try "exactly type `u`", because I assumed it would be banned. But ... I can now dispose of @Fyodor's line of questions about whether there might be some residual restrictions:

The minimal language extensions I need are `MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances` -- which I'm relaxed about; they're long-standing/stable/well-tried. I don't even need `FunctionalDependencies`. And this also works in Hugsmode.

```
class Functorish2 f  where
  fmapish2 :: (FConstr2 f a b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b    -- huh? compiles ok
instance Functorish2 f  where                               -- needs FlexibleInstances
  fmapish2 = fmapish3

class FConstr2 f a b  where fmapish3 :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

-- IOW same signature as fmap. This gives me a free hand.

instance (Eq b) => FConstr2 Set a b  where                  -- needs FlexibleInstances
  fmapish3 f NilSet = NilSet
  fmapish3 f (ConsSet x xs) = uqCons (f x) (fmapish3 f xs)
    where uqCons fx xss | fElem fx xss = xss
                        | otherwise    = ConsSet fx xss
          fElem fx (ConsSet y ys) = fx == y || fElem fx ys
          fElem fx NilSet         = False
```

And indeed `fmapish2 toUpper mySet` squishes out the duplicates. More realistically, a `Set` implementation would use a BST or hashmap or some such, so the constraint on elements would be more complex than `Eq b`. Never the less, seems I can add any constraints on the elements of the `Set`.

Or is there a catch? Is this a fault I could abuse to cause type-unsafety? Presumably the Language Report restriction (next para) doesn't want to allow `fmapish2` to be less polymorphic than the class head would indicate.

The surprise is the line I've marked "huh?". According to the 2010 Language Report Section 4.3.1 'Class Declarations' constraints on method signatures "The *cxi* may constrain only *w-bar*; in particular, the *cxi* may not constrain *u*." -- the *u* being the tyvar(s) from the class head. (BTW the `deriving (Eq)` on `Set` isn't essential.)

The second surprise is that not only does this work in GHC (8.10.2, 7.10), it also works in Hugs (2006).

(Code from original q.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE  MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, 
          UndecidableInstances   #-}

import Data.Char                                          -- toUpper

class Functorish f  where
  fmapish :: (FConstr (f b)) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b    -- huh? compiles ok

class FConstr fb  where fMerge :: fb -> fb -> fb

instance Functorish Set  where
  fmapish f NilSet         = NilSet
  fmapish f (ConsSet x xs) = fMerge (ConsSet (f x) NilSet) (fmapish f xs)

instance (Eq a) => FConstr (Set a)  where            
  fMerge (ConsSet x NilSet) yss | fElem x yss = yss
                                | otherwise   = ConsSet x yss
        where fElem x (ConsSet y ys) = x == y || fElem x ys
              fElem x NilSet         = False
```

Comment: You did put the constraint in the class. Your `Functorish` can only map types that are semigroups (your `FConstr` is [`Semigroup`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-18.5/base-4.14.1.0/Prelude.html#t:Semigroup) btw). And yes, the semigroup constraint is enough for a set, because set can be a semigroup. But you did that by limiting what can be `Functorish`. Your constraint is in the class, not in the instance.

Comment: In `FConstr` I could have a method (say) `fCleanUp :: fb -> fb` s.t. `fmapish` calls `fCleanUp $ ConsSet (f x) (fmapish f xs)` to squish out the duplicates after mapping over them. Again not pretty. It'll need some headscratching to find scalable methods. It's being able to put constraints on elements (that are not type params to `Functorish`) that's crucial.

Comment: You have to come up with `fCleanup` that works for every possible functor. Can you prove that's possible? But the problem is not actually limited to functors. Can you prove it's possible for every type class as well? Doesn't that kind of defeat the idea of type classes in the first place?

Comment: I  suppose another way to put it would be: "no, you can't have different instances put different constraints on the type parameter, but I've got something better: how about the SAME constraint in all instances?"

Comment: "You have to come up with `fCleanup` that works for every possible functor." Not necessarily. I put a variety of methods in `FConstr`. Each instance implements only those methods it needs.

Comment: "how about the SAME constraint in all instances?". Then that's a constraint on the method in the class decl.

Comment: A variety of methods will still have to be "universal" in the sense that at least one works for every possible instance. You still haven't solved the problem in general. But now it's actually even worse: because some methods might be unimplementable for some types (like you say, every instance only implements what it needs), you very type unsafety.

Comment: Huh. My reading of the spec does make it seem like that constraint should be rejected. I decided to check if any of the extensions you enabled relax the rules around there, and I discovered your code is still accepted without any of those extensions enabled. My only conclusion is that spec implementers must have taken a very narrow reading of that restriction, and decided it applies only to constraints on *exactly* the type `u`, not all type expressions including `u`.

Comment: Thanks @Carl. Hugs in H1998 mode rejects the code. That 'Huh?' surely needs `FlexibleContexts` -- I'll check further.

Comment: Maybe [`ConstrainedClassMethods`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/constrained_class_methods.html) is relevant? It is implied by `MultiParamTypeClasses`. That could explain the difference with the report. See also [this GHC issue](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/7854).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The surprise is the line I've marked "huh?". According to the 2010 Language Report Section 4.3.1 'Class Declarations' constraints on method signatures "The cxi may constrain only w-bar; in particular, the cxi may not constrain u." -- the u being the tyvar(s) from the class head. (BTW the deriving (Eq) on Set isn't essential.)

Turning my comment into an answer, I think the relevant GHC extension is called [`ConstrainedClassMethods`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/constrained_class_methods.html) which is implied by `MultiParamTypeClasses`.

For example, this code doesn't compile:

```hs
class Test a where
  test :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

You'll get the error:

```
Test.hs:2:3: error:
    • Constraint ‘Eq a’ in the type of ‘test’
        constrains only the class type variables
      Enable ConstrainedClassMethods to allow it
    • When checking the class method:
        test :: forall a. (Test a, Eq a) => a -> a -> Bool
      In the class declaration for ‘Test’
  |
2 |   test :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you enable `ConstraintClassMethods` then it does compile.

In your case `ConstraintedClassMethods` is implied by `MultiParamTypeClasses`, which also fixes the error in this test example.

But even without that, it would compile, because the `FConstr2 f a b` constraint constrains more than just the variables mentioned in the instance head. See this example from the linked GHC guide, in particular `op5`:

> ```
> class C a where
>   op3 :: Eq a => a -> a    -- Rejected: constrains class variable only
>   op4 :: D b => a -> b     -- Accepted: constrains a locally-quantified variable `b`
>   op5 :: D (a,b) => a -> b -- Accepted: constrains a locally-quantified variable `b`
> ```

So the constraint `FConstr2 f a b` would also be accepted, because it constrains locally-quantified variables `a` and `b`.

Comment: I don't think that's right. `class Test f where { test :: Eq (f a) => f a -> f a -> Bool }` compiles without `ConstrainedClassMethods`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout you're right, I added some extra clarification at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you, good sleuthing both. I was going to ask if there's something deeply type-theoretic here (like it making the method less polymorphic than it should be). The User Guide says "The restriction is a pretty stupid one in the first place." So I guess it's someone in the 1990's (H98 Report has same wording) being ultra-cautious.

Answer (score 0):

The `Functorish2` class does not do anything useful. You could achieve the same by using `fmapish3` directly. The signature is

```
fmapish2 :: (Functorish2 f, FConstr2 f a b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

but since you've given **every** `f :: Type -> Type` an instance `Functorish2 f`, this doesn't actually constrain anything and you could indeed write again

```
fmapish :: FConstr2 f a b => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
fmapish = fmapish2
```

IOW, all your question (in the edited version as of 2021-08-04 01:10:56Z) is about is whether `MultiParamTypeClasses` are adequate for expressing constrained functors. Which I'd answer, *kind of*. They can express the constraints for any given situation, though I'd expect always carrying around the three `f`, `a` and `b` gets awkward quickly.

In practice, the instances would probably tend to have the form

```
instance (FDomCstr a, FCodomCstr b) => FConstr2 F a b where
  ...
```

so maybe it would actually be better to lay it out this way:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Kind (Type, Constraint)

class CFunctor f where
  type DomCstr f a :: Constraint
  type DomCstr f a = ()
  type CodomCstr f b :: Constraint
  type CodomCstr f b = ()
  cfmap :: (DomCstr f a, CodomCstr f b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance CFunctor Set where
  type CodomCstr Set a = Ord a
  cfmapish3 f NilSet = NilSet
  cfmapish3 f (ConsSet x xs) = ...
```

Comment: You've not explained whether this is breaking the restriction in the Language Report: if it is, how does `Functorish2` compile?; if it isn't, why is the restriction there/what does it mean? I put a dummy instance for `Functorish2` just to minimise the code. More realistically, I'd expect instances for most type constrs would look like `Functor` instances today (with a empty instance for `FConstr2`); only type constrs needing extra constraints would pass through to an overloading for `fmapish3`.

Comment: But that doesn't buy you anything. If you're going to have the `FConstr2` constraint around anyway, you can as well use it and define all the instance implementations in that class.

Comment: And I don't know what “restriction in the Language Report” you're talking about.