# instance constraints compare type-family constraints

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functor, type-families

Usually I reckon `type-families` are similarly expressive as compared with `typeclasses`/instances -- the difference is awkwardness/ergonomics of the code. In this case I have code working with `type-families` to raise a `constraint`, but the equivalent `typeclass` code won't compile. (`* Could not deduce (Eq a) ...` when `(Eq a)` is exactly the constraint I'm supplying.) Is this a case `typeclasses` just can't express, or am I doing something wrong?

```
data Set a = NilSet | ConsSet a (Set a)    deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

-- fmap over a Set, squishing out duplicates
fmapSet :: (Eq a, Eq b ) => (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b 
fmapSet f NilSet = NilSet
fmapSet f (ConsSet x xs) = uqCons (f x) (fmapSet f xs)

uqCons fx fxs | sElem fx fxs = fxs
              | otherwise = ConsSet fx fxs
sElem fx NilSet = False
sElem fx (ConsSet fy fys) = fx == fy ||  sElem fx fys
```

I want to call that `fmap` via a `Functor`-like class, with a constraint that the data-structure is well-formed. Either of these approaches with `type-families` work ([based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68647350/2840542), but preferring a standalone family).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Kind (Type, Constraint)

type family   WFTF (f :: * -> *) a :: Constraint
type instance WFTF Set a           =  Eq a

class WFTFFunctor f  where
  wftFfmap :: (WFTF f a, WFTF f b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
instance WFTFFunctor Set  where
  wftFfmap = fmapSet

type family   WFTF2 c_a     :: Constraint 
type instance WFTF2 (Set a) =  Eq a

class WFTF2Functor f  where
  wftF2fmap :: (WFTF2 (f a), WFTF2 (f b)) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
instance WFTF2Functor Set  where
  wftF2fmap = fmapSet
```

The equivalent (I think) `typeclass` at least compiles providing I don't give an implementation for the method:

```
class WFT c_a  where  
instance Eq a => WFT (Set a)

class WFTFunctor f  where
  wftfmap :: (WFT (f a), WFT (f b)) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b 
instance WFTFunctor Set  where wftfmap f xss   =  undefined     -- s/b fmapSet f xss
```

Inferred `:t (\ f (xss :: Set a) -> wftfmap f xss) :: (Eq a, Eq b) => (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b` -- which is exactly the type of `fmapSet`. But if I put that call to `fmapSet f xss` in place of `undefined`, rejected:

```
* Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from a use of `fmapSet'
  from the context: (WFT (Set a), WFT (Set b))
    bound by the type signature for:
               wftfmap :: forall a b.
                          (WFT (Set a), WFT (Set b)) =>
                          (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
    at ...
  Possible fix:
    add (Eq a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        wftfmap :: forall a b.
                   (WFT (Set a), WFT (Set b)) =>
                   (a -> b) -> Set a -> Set b
```

`WFT (Set a)` <s>implies</s> raises Wanted `(Eq a)`, so I shouldn't need to add it. (And if I do via `InstanceSignatures`, rejected because it's not as general as the inferred constraint.) [In response to @dfeuer's answer/my comment] True that there's nothing in the instance decl to Satisfy `(Eq a)`, but `fmapSet`'s sig also Wants `(Eq a)` so (why) doesn't that ensure the constraint gets satisfied at the call site?

I've tried decorating everything with `ScopedTypeVariables/PatternSignatures` to make the constraints more explicit. I've tried switching on `ImpredicativeTypes` (GHC 8.10.2). I sometimes get different rejection messages, but nothing that compiles.

If I take away the `WFT (Set a)` and `(Eq a)` from `fmapSet`'s signature, I get a similar rejection `* Could not deduce (Eq b) ...`. Yes I know that rejection message is a FAQ. In the q's I've looked through, the constraint is indeed unsatisfiable. But then in this case

a) why does the version with implementation `undefined` typecheck;
b) isn't the constraint wanted from `WFT (Set a)` getting satisfied
by `fmapSet` having the `(Eq a)`?)

**Addit:** To explain a bit more about what I'm expecting in terms of Wanted/Satisfied constraints:

There's no signature given for `uqCons`, nor for `sElem`, which it calls. In `sElem` there's a call to `(==)`, that raises Wanted `(Eq b)` in `sElem`'s sig, which gets passed as a Wanted in the sig for `uqCons`, which gets passed as a Wanted in the sig for `fmapSet`, which does have a sig given including `(Eq b)`.

Similarly the `Set` instance for method `wftfmap` raises Wanted `(Eq a, Eq b)`; I expect it can use that to Satisfy the Wanted arising from the call to `fmapSet`.

Comment: It's simply not the case that `WFT (Set a)` implies `Eq a` for every `a`. In particular, I could write e.g. `instance WFT (Set (Int -> Int))` for which this implication is false. For the type families version, I cannot write `type instance WFTF2 (Set (Int -> Int)) = ()` because open type families may not overlap, whereas type class instances may overlap.

Comment: Because type families compute, say for example the type `forall a . WFTF2 (Set a) => Dict (Eq a)` is precisely the same as `forall a . Eq a => Dict (Eq a)` (you can see this in GHCI, try e.g. `:kind! forall a . WFTF2 (Set a) => Dict (Eq a)`). In that case, your Wanted constraint is `Eq a` and your Have constraint is `Eq a` - this case is trivial. For the type class version, you have that `WFT (Set a) => Dict (Eq a)` does not compute; your Wanted is `Eq a` but you have only `WFT (Set a)` - these are unrelated constraints and your Wanted is not satisfied.

Comment: @user2407038 `instance WFT (Set (Int -> Int))` would be an overlapping instance, so if I switch off that extension and `-XNoFlexibleInstances` (or run in H2010 mode), will the compiler commit to `instance WFT (Set a)` so that it can uncover the `(Eq a)`? It seems not to -- but that may be because GHC is not really H2010-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

There's a huge difference between superclass constraints and instance constraints. A superclass constraint is something required to form any instance of the class, and is available whenever the subclass constraint is in force. An instance constraint is required to form a specific instance, and is *not* automatically available when the class constraint is in force. This difference is pretty deeply wired into the system, and is reflected in the Core representations. In Core:

1. A class is a type of records of class methods *and superclasses*.
2. An instance is a value of a class type *or* a function from its instance constraints to such a value.

Once a "dictionary function" is called to produce an instance dictionary, you only have the dictionary, not the arguments that were used to create it.

Comment: Thanks David, but dictionary-passing is an implementation technique, that doesn't explain the semantics. Can you explain please in terms of Wanted and Satisfied constraints? (I'm not seeing an answer to my b)/ the error says `Cannot deduce (Eq a)` and yet `(Eq a)` is exactly what type inference does deduce for the `undefined` equation -- as a Wanted.) (I'll reword the q to avoid the "implies".)

Comment: @AntC It probably isn't deducing it for `undefined`, why do you think it is? `undefined` doesn't need `Eq a`, but when you call `fmapSet` you do. The context `WFTF (Set a)` on `wftfmap` doesn't satisfy `Eq a`; it would if `Eq a` was required by the *class* `WFTF`, but it doesn't when it's only required by one particular instance (even if you think that is the only instance that could be in use).

Comment: @Ben, it is deducing: in the q I give the inferred type for `wftfmap` applied to a `Set`. That's with the instance equation `= undefined`.

Comment: @AntC That's inferring it as something you **need** to **call** `wftfmap`, not something you **have** on the inside to *implement* `wftfmap`. You need it to use the `WFTF (Set a)` instance; it comes entirely from the type signature of `wftfmap`, nothing to do with the code of the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> [re @Ben's comment to @dfeuer's answer] not something you **have** on the inside to *implement* wftfmap.

OK I can have the right sig on the inside:

```
-- class/instance WFT, funcs fmapSet, uqCons, sElem as before

{-# LANGUAGE  InstanceSigs,  QuantifiedConstraints #-}

class WFTQFunctor f  where
  wftQfmap :: (WFT (f a), WFT (f b)) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b       

instance (forall b. (WFT (Set b) => Eq b)) => WFTQFunctor Set  where 
  wftQfmap :: (Eq a, Eq b) => (a -> b) -> (Set a) -> (Set b)        -- yay
  wftQfmap f xss = fmapSet f xss
```

Compiles with a warning that I can suppress with `-XMonoLocalBinds`:

```
* The constraint `WFT (Set b)' matches
    instance Eq a => WFT (Set a)
  This makes type inference for inner bindings fragile;
    either use MonoLocalBinds, or simplify it using the instance
* In the instance declaration for `WFTQFunctor Set'
```

I appreciate that `QuantifiedConstraint` is a fib. I might have `instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} WFT (Set (b -> c))` for which `Eq` does not hold; but I don't; and/or at least if I use a `Set` element for which `Eq` holds, I'll get away with it(?)

But no:

```
*> wftQfmap toUpper mySet                -- mySet :: Set Char

<interactive>:2:1: error:
* Could not deduce (Eq b) arising from a use of `wftQfmap'
  from the context: WFT (Set b)
    bound by a quantified context at <interactive>:2:1-22
  Possible fix: add (Eq b) to the context of a quantified context
* In the expression: wftQfmap toUpper mySet
  In an equation for `it': it = wftQfmap toUpper mySet
```

So why does that `instance WFTQFunctor Set` compile? And can it ever do anything useful?

Answer (score 0):

OK I have something working. It's ugly and clunky, and not scalable, but answers the q as put:

```
class WFT c_a  where  
  isWF :: c_a -> Bool                                -- is c_a well-formed?
  mkWF :: c_a -> c_a                                 -- edit c_a to make it well-formed
  mkWF = id
instance Eq a => WFT (Set a)                         -- instance types same as q
  isWF NilSet         = True
  isWF (ConsSet x xs) = not (sElem x xs) && isWF xs  -- sElem decl'd in the q
  mkWF = fmapSet id                                  -- fmapSet also

class WFTFunctor f  where                            -- class as decl'd in the q
  wftfmap :: (WFT (f a), WFT (f b)) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b 
instance WFTFunctor Set  where wftfmap f xss   = mkWF $ fmap f xss 


instance Functor Set  where                          -- conventional/unconstrained fmap
  fmap f  NilSet        = NilSet
  fmap f (ConsSet x xs) = ConsSet (f x) (fmap f xs)
```

If I'm using `fmap`, generalise:

```
class Functor f => WFTFunctor f  where
  wftfmap :: (WFT (f a), WFT (f b)) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b   
  wftfmap f xss = mkWF $ fmap f xss
```

This is not far off H2010 compliant. (Needs `FlexibleConstraints`.) So I can get the `Eq` constraint effective 'inside' the `WFTFunctor` instance; it needs a method call from `WFT` to pull it through.

I could have heaps of other methods in class `WFT`, but I say "not scalable" because you couldn't in general 'edit' an ill-formed structure to well-formed. Hmm since it's a `Functor`: could unload to a `List` then load back to the structure.