# Functors in Haskell: showing the value of an item of the type of the type parameter

Tags: haskell

GHC does not know how to show Type a.

```
data FunctorExample a = FunctorExample { val1 :: a, 
                                         val2 :: String
                                        } deriving (Show) 

instance Functor FunctorExample where
    fmap f (FunctorExample x y) = FunctorExample (f x) (y ++ " " ++ show x)
```

I've tried a number of things, including: setting a type constraint in data (now deprecated), and using {-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-} to add a constraint for fmap and adding the type signature suggested below, with no success (though it's possible my type signature was flawed...).

```
    * No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of `show'
      Possible fix:
        add (Show a) to the context of
          the type signature for:
            fmap :: forall a b.
                    (a -> b) -> FunctorExample a -> FunctorExample b
```

Is there no standard way of constraining a to be a Show instance? It happens to always be an Int in my usage.

Comment: Even if this were allowed, it wouldn't be a lawful functor instance. `fmap id` would not be the identity function, taking eg `FunctorExample 1 ""` to `FunctorExample 1 " 1"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this isn't a lawful functor without id.  Also, I presume functor type parameters cannot be constrained?

Comment: The standard `Functor`, `Monad`, etc. classes do not allow you to constrain types `a`, `b`. As defined, a `Functor` must implement `fmap :: (a->b) -> f a -> f b` for any `a` and `b`, without constraints. In the libraries there are some variant of these standard classes allowing constraints, but they are not commonly used. See e.g. https://hackage.haskell.org/package/subcategories and `CFunctor` for constrained functors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: Forgive me if I make any blunders or approach the question differently, I'm also a Haskell learner myself.</sup>

The first thing I'd like to point out is that your definition `fmap` does not comply with the two [functor laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor#Functor_Laws). These laws exist so that "*the behaviour of `fmap` remains predictable*".

The first law states that `fmap id functor` should be no different from `id functor` (i.e. `fmap id = id`). Just eyeballing the definition, we can see that this:

```
fmap id (FunctorExample x y) = FunctorExample (id x) (y ++ ...)
```

...isn't going to fly, since the value of the second `y` is prone to change.

The second law states that `fmap (f . g) = fmap f . fmap g`. I'll leave it to you as an exercise to check if it complies or not.

What I'll suggest here is to use a different function instead, then there's no burden of complying with functor laws. This way, you can use type-class constraints.

```
propagate :: Show a => (a -> b) -> FunctorExample a -> FunctorExample b
propagate f (FunctorExample x y) = FunctorExample (f x) (y ++ " " ++ show x)
```

Now, maybe you had a particular purpose in mind with `fmap`. I'm not entirely sure. Maybe you meant to use `FunctorExample` in other functions which take functors. (I'm guessing so by the name.) If so, consider redesigning the `fmap` definition so that it complies with the functor laws.

To clarify, constraining the type of `fmap` [is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345055/how-to-add-a-class-constraint-to-a-functor-instance-declaration-in-haskell).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this was not a functor. The point of the exercise was to become familiar with common gluing patterns - functors, applicatives, monads. I suppose this means that using these patterns implies type-class restrictions are not possible?

Comment: I guess this answers it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345055/how-to-add-a-class-constraint-to-a-functor-instance-declaration-in-haskell

Comment: Yes it does, thanks! Didn't find that particular thread somehow...

Comment: By extension, I presume applicatives and monads also cannot have type restrictions...

Comment: TrebledJ, could you please edit this into your answer so I can accept it?